# Filter different identical characters in multiple words

Tags: command-line

I have a very large wordlist. How can I use Unix (or possibly Python) to find instances of multiple words fitting specific character-sharing criteria? For example, I want Words 1 and 2 to have the same fourth and seventh characters, Words 2 and 3 to have the same fourth and ninth characters, and Words 3 and 4 to have the same second, fourth, and ninth characters.

Example:

```
aaadiigjlf
abcdefghij
aswdofflle
bbbbbbbbbb
bisofmlwpa
fsbdfopkld
gikfkwpspa
hogkellgis
```

might return

```
abcdefghij
aaadiigjlf
fsbdfopkld
aswdofflle
```

EDIT: For clarification, I need the code to return any words that share the same characters in given positions; I don't have specific characters (like "d" and "g" as given in the example) in mind. Also, I'd like it to be able to return words that don't fit ALL of the criteria; e.g. in the example given, Words 1 and 4 share a fourth character, but not necessarily the second, seventh, and ninth. With the program I'm running in its finished form, I'm expecting it to return a very small list of words (probably only ten) based on nine strict character-sharing criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` which uses [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
# Find all lines where the fourth and seventh letter are "d" and "g"
grep '...d..g'  somefile

# Find all lines where the fourth and ninth letters are "d" and "l"
grep '...d....l' somefile
```

If you want to enforce *both* rules, you would chain them together using a pipe:

```
grep '...d..g' somefile | grep '...d....l'
```

You can reduce the verbosity of a regex and multiple dots using the syntax `{123}` instead of 123 dots, such as:

```
egrep '.{3}d.{2}g' somefile
```

Note that as your regular expression gets more complicated you may need to use the `egrep` to support some syntax, such as the repetition syntax above.

Comment: Sorry, I need the code to return any words that share the same characters in given positions; I don't have specific characters (like "d" and "g" as given in the example) in mind. Also, I'd like it to be able to return multiple words that don't fit the same criteria; e.g. in the example given, Words 1 and 4 share a fourth character, but not necessarily the second, seventh, and ninth.

Comment: That's more complicated and likely would need to be done with a real programming language such as Python. It may be possible with `awk` but overall I can't think of a (clean) "unix" way to do that.

Comment: Hmm...then should I re-ask this in a Python forum, or would I still be able to ask here?

Comment: It's possible someone has a wizardly way of doing it that I'm not aware of, so I'm interested if anyone here can solve it. You might also want to post the exact question on [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) as well as [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)